# One or two managedObjectContext

Tags: iphone, ios, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I am currently developing an application which makes HTTP request (via AsiHTTPRequest) then parse a JSON stream. Basically there is a tableView/NSFetchedResultsController, which print objects fetched from coreData, and the refresh is hand-done via a UIButton. I want my page to see the changes (so I implemented the NSFetchedResultsController).

But if the user refresh in the underground for instance, then the parsing will be differed, waiting for the answer of the request. Meanwhile the user can navigate and click on a Core Data object, which ca be deleted while he's reading it.

What would happen ?
Also, what is the best moment to save the context ?
Or is it better to use 2 context and then synchronise them ?

Thanks in advance for your opinions.

Niels

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a good use of the NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate, only one NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate is sufficient.

Hope it helps,
Niels